# Base Class reference to Pointer of Derived Class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

I would like to have, in a base class A, a reference (or pointer if not possible) to a pointer in a derived class.
This would look like this :

```
 BaseClassController
        {
          public :
            //Constructors, destructor,...

          protected :
            BaseDataClass *& m_current;
        }

DerivedClassAController : public BaseClassController
    {
      public :
        //Constructors, destructor,...

      protected :
        DerivedDataClassA * m_currentA;
    }

DerivedClassBController : public BaseClassController
    {
      public :
        //Constructors, destructor,...

      protected :
        DerivedDataClassB * m_currentB;
    }
```

with the Data classes being :

```
BaseDataClass
{
    void doSomething();
}

DerivedDataClassA : public BaseDataClass
{
 //...
}

DerivedDataClassB : public BaseDataClass
{
 //...
}
```

What I would like to do next in BaseClassController is :

```
BaseClassController::someFunction(){
    m_current->doSomething();
}
```

The problem is that the objects pointed by m_currentA and m_currentB will change a lot through the life of the program, and I would like the m_current reference to change automatically when the derived class pointer changes.
Concretly, I would like the function changing the object pointed by m_currentA to look like this :

```
DerivedClassAController::changerCurrentA(DerivedDataClassA* ptA){
   m_currentA = ptA;
}
```

and not like this :

```
DerivedClassAController::changerCurrentA(DerivedDataClassA* ptA){
   m_currentA = ptA;
   m_current = ptA;
}
```

I tried by passing the pointer in the derived class constructor :

```
BaseClassController::BaseClassController(BaseDataClass* pt)
 : m_current(pt)
{
}

DerivedClassAController::DerivedClassAController()
 : BaseClassController(m_currentA),
   m_current(A)
{
}
```

But I ended up having a m_current pointing to a DerivedDataClassB in DerivedClassAController.

Is this acheivable ? Or is there a better way to do that ?

**Note :**
DerivedClassAController will use m_currentA as a DerivedDataClassA 95% of the time. Using only the m_current pointer in the base class will end putting dynamic_cast(m_current) everywhere.

Comment: `polymorphism` - have you tried it? Can you do everything you need through the `m_current` pointer?

Comment: `virtual BaseDataClass* GetCurrent() = 0;` in `BaseClassController`, and have the two derived controllers implement it and return the current value of `m_currentA` or `m_currentB`, respectively.

Comment: LogicStuff - I added a note to explain why I Can't do it like you suggest. Igor - That could work yes ! I Will try. But I would also like to know if it could work the way I tried

Comment: As written in your example, `BaseClassController` constructor binds the reference to the local variable `pt` (a copy of `m_currentA`). The reference becomes dangling as soon as the constructor returns.

Comment: I did not think of that... How should I pass it ?

Comment: No, you cannot make `m_current` magically change together with `m_currentA`. `BaseDataClass` is not necessarily located at offset zero inside `DerivedDataClassA` - in other words, `m_currentA` may not represent the same memory address as `(BaseDataClass*)m_currentA`. And you cannot produce two distinct addresses with a single assignment.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks a lot for your answers ! :) I will try your getCurrent implementation

Comment: As a blanket recommendation: *"don't mess around with 'pointers to things.'"* When you do this, you make a situation that is very fragile and hard to maintain, even if "it seems to work." Instead of letting one class "know how another class works," accessing protected data from it, I suggest that "each class should be responsible for itself." Provide *methods* and *properties,* overriding them as need be, and generally don't pass-around "pointers." Let **all** the code that might affect an object's internal state be ***inside*** that class-definition (or its parent).

Comment: Thank for your suggestion Mike, I will take it into account for later !

Comment: Have you tried using virtual functions and put the behaviour you require for `DerivedA` instances into the `DerivedA` class, and the `DerivedB` behaviour in `DerivedB`? Therefore no need to do dynamic_cast in the base class because the correct derived function gets called

Comment: No I didn't. In the program DerivedA and DerivedB are extremely different and there base class is just there to factorize the identical behaviour they have. Your suggestion is possible but I do not think it is suitable for my use. I could have given more info about DerivedA and DerviedB but I focused on what was the important part for me, but thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that following approach would work: Instead of using a member reference, create a virtual function in `BaseClassController` that returns a copy of the pointer:

```
struct BaseClassController {
    virtual BaseDataClass* m_current() = 0;
```

And implement it differently in each derived controller:

```
BaseDataClass* DerivedDataClassA::m_current() {
    return m_currentA;
```

Comment: ... and, I suggest, whenever possible, put the code that would need to *use* that pointer, **inside** the object itself, or its parent(s), so that it isn't necessary to return a pointer at all. That way, "I don't have to go running all over the source-code of the application" to discover all the ways that a particular thing is being manipulated. It's all right here."  And if (or rather, *when)* something needs to be changed, it only needs to be changed "once, right here."

Comment: It is what I do when possible. The application developped is a CAD using a lot of the MVC Design Pattern. The Controller manipulates the Data Class through a pointer but the rest of the program calls the functions of the Controller. The pointer is not going anywhere away from the controller class and its base class.